# Bash - Get output from non-blocking command

Tags: bash, python-2.7

I have a python program main.py which produces some outputs which I would like to write to a file. I want to execute the program non-blocking. Usually I would use `python2.7 main.py > main.out &` or `nohup python2.7 main.py &> main.out &`.

My problem is, that the program may run very long, and I want to have access to the output created so far before the program terminates. When I execute `python2.7 main.py > main.out` and I then stop the program with Ctrl-C the output file has the output created so far. However, with the nonblocking commands, the output-file remains empty during execution, and after I kill the program.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `-u` flag for python which will run the python process with unbuffered stdout/stderr

```
python2.7 -u main.py > main.out &
```